# How can I hide the flickring bottom bar with save and cancel in mobile mode?

Tags: mdriven

I have set `hideSideBar=true` and still in mobile and tablet mode the bottom bar with save and cancel flickers when `selfVM.save` is called. There is a bottom bar even when not saving hiding content in mobil and tablet mode.

How can I hide the bottom bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can always add a CSS rule that hides them.

Comment: and such a CSS rule could be made to a specific page only if needed as this updated wiki page describes: https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Hide_left_menu